# java prompt + get a string contain any space (one or more)

Tags: java, prompt

I need get a String from prompt, and juste after I need get a String list from prompt. I have a problem. When I get my list, I have only the first word. I try any other `nextLine()` ... but do not work. I see lot of sample with juste 2 words (one space) but i looking for a list of word!!

**Java code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name:");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter a name list:");
    String nameList = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String lastName = input.next();
    input.close();
    System.out.println(name + " * " + nameList + " ** " + lastName);
}
```

**console result:**

```
Enter a name:
aa
Enter a name list:
bb cc dd
Enter last name:
aa * bb ** cc
```

1st response is aa + enter

2nd response is bb cc dd + enter

but juste after dd + enter, the program display `Enter last name:
aa * bb ** cc` and stop

Comment: Personally, I'd use `nextLine` for all the prompts and then a second `Scanner` to parse the "list" of values, but that's me - Remember, `next` will read the next token up to the next white space, so `nameList`, follows by `lastName` means that there are still tokens in the `Scanner` which `lastName` is picking up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution** `.nextLine()` **but on all lines**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name:");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a name list:");
    String nameList = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    System.out.println(name + " * " + nameList + " ** " + lastName);
}
```

**Console:**

```
Enter a name:
aa
Enter a name list:
bb cc dd
Enter last name:
ee
aa * bb cc dd ** ee
```

Comment: Yes, but can you explain why ;)?

Comment: I tryed with next() on simple (1 and 3) and nextLine() only on 2