# java prompt + get number before get a string contain any space (one or more)

Tags: java, prompt

I need get a number from prompt, and juste after I need get a String list from prompt. I have a problem. Is it OK if the 1st question ask a string with `nextLine()` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438063/java-prompt-get-a-string-contain-any-space-one-or-more).

**Java code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a name list:");
    String nameList = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    System.out.println(num + " * " + nameList + " ** " + lastName);
}
```

**console result:**

```
Enter a number:
2
Enter a name list:
Enter last name:
```

1st response is 2 + enter

but juste after 2 + enter, the program display `Enter a name list:
    Enter last name:`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution add `input.nextLine();` juste after `int num = input.nextInt();`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a name list:");
    String nameList = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    System.out.println(num + " * " + nameList + " ** " + lastName);
}
```

**console:**

```
Enter a number:
2
Enter a name list:
aa bb cc
Enter last name:
dd
2 * aa bb cc ** dd
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `input.next()` instead of `input.nextLine()` as `next` blocks for user input while `nextLine` moves the scanner past the current line and it buffers all the inputs until it finds a line separator.

or use `nextLine()` after `nextInt` to consume the linefeed which is left by nextInt